# Re-direct after restoring mysql database into magento

Tags: mysql, magento-1.7

Having a bit of a problem. I've got a dev site and a live site. Both built in Magento. So i make the changes on the dev site and then deploy them to the live site. However i had to rollback some changes i made on the dev site. I also restored the database from the live site to the dev site so they were in sync. However since i've restored the database from the live site to dev. The URL keeps redirecting to the live URL.

It's like i've setup something in apache but i've not done anything. I'm guessing it's something in the Magento config but if i try and log into the admin panel it just redirects me to the live site.

Restore commade I ran:

```
mysql -u username -p dbname < mysqldatbasefile
```

Any ideas? Kinda stuck!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Megento dev site re-directing to live site URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015728/megento-dev-site-re-directing-to-live-site-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the base url of your instance.
Look in the `core_config_data` table for records with `path = 'web/unsecure/base_url'` and `path = 'web/unsecure/base_link_url'` and change their values to the appropriate url. Clear the cache when you are done.